# Black jack program using gui

Tags: java

hello i am writing a black jack program and i want to be able to display the cards that i made.. i imported images of each card and and assigned each to a specific suit and card number using cases then i made a deck which is a stack and added each card into the that. i made a method that shuffles the card deck and pops the first one. I want to display each card each time a button is pressed, how do i do that?

my code...

```
public class CardList {

    private Stack<Cards> list;

    public CardList(){
        list = new Stack<Cards>();


        for(Cards.CardSuit suit:Cards.CardSuit.values()){
            for(int i=1; i<=13; i++){
                list.push(new Cards(suit, i));
            }
        }
    }

    public Cards getCard()
    {
        shuffle();
        return list.pop();

    }

    public void shuffle(){
        Collections.shuffle(list);
    }
}


public class Cards 
{

    public enum CardSuit{DIAMOND, SPADE, CLUB, HEART};

    private BufferedImage image;
    int num; 
    CardSuit s;


    public Cards(CardSuit suit, int number){
        num = number;
        s = suit;
        image = createCard(suit, number);
    }   



    public Cards() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    public BufferedImage createCard(CardSuit s , int num)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
            case DIAMOND :
                switch (num)
                {   
                    case 1:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("ad.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 2: 
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("2d.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 3: 
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("3d.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 4:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("4d.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 5:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("5d.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 6:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("6d.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 7:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("7d.GIF"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 8:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("8d.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 9:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("9d.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 10:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("td.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 11:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("jd.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 12:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("kd.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                    case 13:
                        try {                
                              image = ImageIO.read(new File("qd.gif"));
                           } catch (IOException ex) {
                                // handle exception...
                           }
                }
            break;  
            case SPADE:
                switch (num)
                {
                case 1:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("as.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 2: 
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("2s.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 3: 
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("3s.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 4:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("4s.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 5:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("5s.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 6:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("6s.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 7:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("7s.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 8:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("8s.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 9:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("9s.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 10:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("ts.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 11:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("jc.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 12:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("ks.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 13:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("qs.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }

                }
            break;  
            case CLUB:
                switch (num)
                {
                case 1:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("ac.gif"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 2: 
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("2c.gif"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 3: 
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("3c.gif"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 4:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("4c.gif"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 5:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("5c.gif"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 6:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("6c.gif"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 7:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("7c.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 8:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("8c.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 9:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("9c.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 10:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("tc.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 11:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("jc.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 12:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("kc.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 13:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("qc.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                }
            break;  
            case HEART:
                switch (num)
                {
                case 1:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("ah.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 2: 
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("2h.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 3: 
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("3h.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 4:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("4h.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 5:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("5h.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 6:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("6h.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 7:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("7h.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 8:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("8h.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 9:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("9h.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 10:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("th.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 11:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("jh.GIF"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 12:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("kh.gif"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                case 13:
                    try {                
                          image = ImageIO.read(new File("qh.gif"));
                       } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // handle exception...
                       }
                }   
        }
        return image;
    }

    public int carNum()
    {
        return num;
    }
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters


     }
     public String toString()
        {
            return  "" +image;

        }
```

Comment: Is this homework or something?

Comment: we are to write a black jack programme but the gui section was my choosing we are not really to use it but i decided to cause we get extra credit.. i added the comments so i come back and complete it most of it is done i just need to display the cards i have tried..       
  if (event.getSource() == hit)
  { 
   
   playerC[i] = cl.getCard();
   
   if(playerC[i]!= null)
   {
    Icon image = (Icon)playerC[i];
    JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(label);
    label.setVisible(true);
   }
   i++;
  }

Comment: I think your `Cards` class has to extend `JComponent` otherwise `paintComponent()` would not get called when required.

Answer (score 0):

Basic gui:

create another class to actually be a main class with a main method. in the main method write:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cards!"); // new window + title
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   //posions the window in the center of the screen
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
JPanel primary = new JPanel(); //the main panel
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS))
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(); //ImageIcon to hod the image
JLabel label = new JLabel(img); //label to hold the icon
JButton btn = new JButton("new card"); //button with text
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //adding the event
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        //event logic
    }
});
primary.add(label);
primary.add(btn);
frame.getContentPane().add(primary); //add the panel to the window
frame.pack(); //resizes everything to fit
frame.setVisible(true);
```

this is the **basic** idea of how the gui part should work.
now the event logic should be something along the lines of:

```
img.setImage(...); //your part of getting the right card image
frame.pack(); //so window size adjusts to the new size
```

You can read more about swing (java gui) in:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: hey thanks.. i actually had the gui class, but was not using the right code, i added the img.setImage(..); and ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(); 
JLabel label = new JLabel(img);  and now i can see the images, thanks alot!!!!!!!!!!!!